# Can't create two separate row divs in a form

Tags: forms

I am trying to have each case be in a specific row. The first row works correctly, however the second row absolutely does not. The field_suffix in the form is far to the left whereas I want it to the right. This appears to be because suffix isn't being put into the correct div ().

This is typically in a use case where first_name will be executed before last_name. What's going on? Why isn't this working?

```
  case 'first_name':
$form[$mapped_field] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  "#prefix" => "<div class='row'>",
);

$form['field_prefix'] = array(
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#title' => 'Prefix',
  '#options' => drupal_map_assoc(client_mod_prefix()),
  "#suffix" => "</div>",
  '#attributes' => array('class' => array('form-control')),
);
break;

  case 'last_name':
$form[$mapped_field] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  "#prefix" => "<div class='row'>",
);

$form['field_suffix'] = array(
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#title' => 'Suffix',
  '#options' => drupal_map_assoc(client_mod_suffix()),
  "#suffix" => "</div>",
  '#attributes' => array('class' => array('form-control')),
);
break;
```

Comment: Perhaps provide a screenshot of what your form looks like, and then another screenshot of the desired outcome? As is, I see a mess of code with a `case` statement building a form and have little clue what you want to achieve.

Comment: This question is about the CSS code and I see no CSS code in your question.